# Tablesorter_filer works fine but need it with a search button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Totally new to jquery and programming. my module has a table with search option (that calls the jquery plugin tablesorter_filter.js) but it works only with text box. i enter a text and the table is searched with key press..i want to include a search button next to the textbox and the tablesorter_filter should be able to search only on click of the search button. are there any plugins with the search button option?
please help

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). Which has what you like and you can change the theme ot this table too. You have to customize this code
1. call a function which is in keypress event   to search button click

Comment: Yeah this is exactly how my search function works. But i hjave no idea how to implement the button to do the work of search